# Horizontal and vertical row in 1 from

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have this problem with multiple rows and the same data in SSRS.
My data set looks like this:

```
ID | name | related ID
1  | 1a   | 5
1  | 1a   | 6
1  | 1a   | 7
```

And i would like to get something like this as a result.

```
ID | Name 
1  | 1A
Related Items: 5 , 6 , 7
```

OR

```
ID | Name         
1  | 1A           
Related Items: 5  | 6 | 7 |
```

But now when i group my row on the ID I get :

```
ID                | Name  | ...        
1                 | 1A    | ...       
Related Items: 5  | 6 | 7 |

Related Items: 5  | 6 | 7 |

Related Items: 5  | 6 | 7 |
```

Can someone explain could display only 1 row with the header data and 1 row with the related item

Comment: Look into column groups.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with this approach...

```
ID | Name 
1  | 1A
Related Items: 5 , 6 , 7
```

since you're using SSRS 2012 you can use the `LookupSet` function to get the string of related items for each `ID` and display this in a simple table.

I have a simple table:

[image]

With one **Row Group** based on `ID`.

The expression is:

```
="Related Items: "
    & Join
    (
        LookupSet
        (
            Fields!ID.Value
            , Fields!ID.Value
            , Fields!relatedID.Value
            , "DataSet1"
        )
        , ", "
    )
```

Which uses `LookupSet` to get a list of matching `relatedID` values for a given `ID`, then uses Join to turn the array returned by `LookupSet` into a string.

With your data:

[image]

This gives the expected results:

[image]

Comment: This works, but If the related item had a type would i be able to use this to seperate the related items by type ? so i could get something like Related Item type A: 5, 6, in an other line related item type b: 7, The type is in the dataset